# How do I move render-blocking javascript below the fold in a small page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small mobile page with a few big js files (including jQuery)

The page speed is pretty slow and the google page speed analysis suggests to move the 'render-blocking javascript below the fold'. My page is pretty small to begin with, so everything on it is already above the fold.

I would normally async the javascript, but the javascript needs to run in order
(First jQuery, then the plugin, and finally my own code which is inline)
So async loading on the code would cause it to run out of order, usually jquery loading last and everything else breaking before hand.

Is there an easy way to push everything below the fold? or at least make the browser treat the javascript like it is below the fold all while loading everything in order?

Comment: Alright, let's say I put it into a file and load it in. How can I have it not block the render of the page and still load in the correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by wrapping the code in a callback after the page loads. Here is the code that I used:

```
    function appendScript(src, callback) {
        callback = callback || function(){};
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = src;
        element.async = false;
        element.onload = callback;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        appendScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", function(){
            appendScript("http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js", doStuff);
        });
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;


    doStuff(){
        // MY CODE HERE
    }
```

I forgot to mention in my question that the code embedded on the page isn't much at all. It is just a few snippets but would be much harder without jquery.

I hope this helps out anyone else who is trying what I tried to do

Answer (score 0):

If all of your content is above the fold you should be able to simply put all of your javascript files towards the bottom of your document and above your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Because the </body> tag is above the fold, the javascript files stop the page from rendering until all the javascript is loaded. I'm trying to have the page render fast and then load the javascript in the correct order.